# Navigating up the DOM, how to get back down?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, html-table

I have a table like this.

```
<table id="order-table">
    <tr class="row-header">
        <td style="width: 80px;">Line #</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">ID #</td>
        <td style="width: 50px;">Qty</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">Desc</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">ABC8</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">UPC</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">NDC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td style="width: 80px;"><input class="row-target" readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 80px; background: lightgray" type="text" value="10"></td>
        <td style="width: 100px;"><input class="id-target" style="width: 100px;" type="text" /></td>
        <td style="width: 50px;"><input class="qty-target" style="width: 50px;" type="text" /></td>
        <td style="width: 100px;"><input readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; background: lightgray" type="text" /></td>
        <td style="width: 100px;"><input readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; background: lightgray" type="text" /></td>
        <td style="width: 100px;"><input readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; background: lightgray" type="text" /></td>
        <td style="width: 100px;"><input readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; background: lightgray" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And some jQuery like this:

```
function checkIdTarget(rownum) { 
    if ($(this).val().length === 8) {
        var rownum = $(this).parent("td").children(".row-target").val();
        alert (rownum);
        var newrow = '<tr class="row"><td style="width: 80px;"><input class="row-target" readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 80px; background: lightgray" type="text" value="' + rownum + '"></td><td style="width: 100px;"><input class="id-target" style="width: 100px;" type="text" /></td><td style="width: 50px;"><input class="qty-target" style="width: 50px;" type="text" /></td><td style="width: 100px;"><input readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; background: lightgray" type="text" /></td><td style="width: 100px;"><input readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; background: lightgray" type="text" /></td><td style="width: 100px;"><input readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; background: lightgray" type="text" /></td><td style="width: 100px;"><input readonly tabindex="-1" style="width: 100px; background: lightgray" type="text" /></td></tr>';
        $(newrow).insertAfter($(this).parents("tr"));
        $("#button-submit-order").button("enable");
    }
    if ($(this).val().length > 8) {
        var x = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(x.slice(0, -1));
        $(this).effect("shake");
    }
    if (isNaN($(this).val())) {
        var x = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(x.slice(0, -1));
        $(this).effect("shake");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to grab the value from the input box with class `row-target` relative to the current ID box which I'm calling `this`. The value is coming back undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is checkIdTarget bound to?

Comment: if `this` is the `id-target` element then `$(this).parent().prev().find('input')`

Comment: you're currently selecting children of the same TD where the original `this` - I presume the input field - is located, which wouldn't work... you need to go 1 level up to a TR instead - `parent('td').parent('tr')`

Comment: @ZathrusWriter not `closest("tr")`?

Comment: good point Archer, it's probably a better idea :)

Answer (score 0):

In your 3rd line of JQuery, you should write the following code:

```
var rownum = $(this).closest("td").find(".row-target").val();
```